# How can I avoid instanceof when function behavior depends on type?

Tags: java, polymorphism, instanceof

I am designing a basic game engine. I have an abstract `GameObject` class which are inherited by two classes `Player` and `Bullet`. I am trying to handle collision of two game objects. If both of the collided objects are the same, nothing happens. If one of them is bullet and other is player, the player's health is set to 0. Here is a snippet showing the required method and class definitions:

```
public interface GameObject {
    void onCollision(GameObject gameObject);
}

public class GameObjectImpl implements GameObject {
    ...
    // By default, do nothing.
    @Override
    public void onCollision(GameObject object) {}    
}


public class Player extends GameObjectImpl {
   ...
   @Override
   public void onCollision(GameObject gameObject) {
      if (gameObject instanceof Player) {
          // Do nothing
      } else if (gameObject instanceof Bullet) {
          this.health = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

I want to avoid `instanceof` but I could not think of any way to do so. I wanted to implement it with using `polymorphism` as clients of `GameObject` interface should not know the details about bullets or players etc. It will just call `onCollision` method for objects in each frame. How can I achieve this with a cleaner code? Thank you.

Comment: That kind of inheritance hierarchy doesn't work very well. While players and bullets may both be "game objects" in the abstract sense, they have very little in common. Methods can't be nicely written to handle different game objects, so you'd have to resort to `instanceof`. That's why game engines tend to use the [Entity-Component-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) model, which avoids inheritance (and [composition should be preferred over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It might look cumbersome because Javas mechanism of resolving target methods is not the best, but you can try something similar to

```
public class Player extends GameObjectImpl {
   ...
    @Override
    public void onCollision(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObject.collideWith(this);
    }
}
```

and then extend the `GameObject` with the appropriate "callback":

```
public interface GameObject {
    void onCollision(GameObject gameObject);
    void collideWith(Player player);
}
```

and then

```
public class Player extends GameObjectImpl {
   ...
    @Override
    public void onCollision(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObject.collideWith(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void collideWith(Player player) {
        // ... do nothing, shouldn't happen
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Bullet extends GameObjectImpl {
   ...
    @Override
    public void onCollision(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObject.collideWith(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void collideWith(Player player) {
        player.setHealth(0);
    }
}
```

For further reading you might search for the Visitor pattern in Java.

Comment: Actually, that is not the “visitor” pattern, it’s “double dispatch”, which the visitor pattern *uses*. Misnaming double dispatch as visitor is a common mistake. Nevertheless, this is the best approach.

Comment: That's why I wrote "Visitor pattern in Java" ;-) But yes "Visitor implementation in Java" would be less confusing maybe.

Comment: But it’s not the visitor pattern at all. Not even slightly.

Comment: True, but I didn't wrote that I implemented the Visitor pattern

Comment: But, isn't it bad that I will end up with many overloaded `collideWith` methods and they will be seen by the client (which I tend to avoid)?

Comment: You can put empty implementations in the super class as you already did it so the subclasses only contain the collisions they need

Comment: But as I already wrote - look up the Visitor pattern how to extract the logic per subclass into another class who's only responsibility is to handle the collisions and then your GameObjects will only contain an interface to "accept" visitors.